# change the indexing in the output in R

Tags: r

I have the data in the following format

```
"1001/02","1003","1004/05","1006"
```

I want the output in the following format

```
1001   1002  1003 1004 1005   1006
```

I run the following set of codes

```
a1<-c("1001/02","1003","1004/05","1006")
b1<-c(1,1,1,1)

z<-sapply(a1,FUN=function(x){1000+as.numeric(strsplit(x,"/")[[1]][2])})
z1<-sapply(a1,FUN=function(x){as.numeric(strsplit(x,"/")[[1]][1])})
a<-data.frame(b1,z1,z)

for(i in 1:4)
{ if(!is.na(a[i,3]))
    {a[seq(i+2,nrow(a)-nrow(a[i,])+i+2),]<-a[seq(i+1,i+nrow(a)-nrow(a[i,])+1),]
        a[i+1,2]<-a[i,3]}
}

output<-a[,1:2]
```

But I get the following output

```
        b1   z1
1001/02  1 1001
1003     1 1002
1004/05  1 1003
1006     1 1004
5        1 1005
6        1 1006
7       NA   NA
8       NA   NA
NA      NA   NA
NA.1    NA   NA
NA.2    NA   NA
```

Please suggest how to change the indexes of the output to 1,2,3...

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: This is my expected o/p 1001   1002  1003 1004 1005   1006

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dat <- c("1001/02","1003","1004/05","1006")
gsub("^0", "100", unlist(strsplit(dat, "/")))
## [1] "1001" "1002" "1003" "1004" "1005" "1006"
```

Comment: Thank you hrbrmstr. You made it look so easy. Saved so may lines of code. Just the o/p I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I belive it can be done with `b1 <- strsplit(a1,"/")` and then

```
z1 <- vector()
k <- 1
for(i in 1:length(b1)){
  z1[k] <- i
    z1[k+1:length(b1[[i]])] <- b1[[i]]
  k<-k+1+length(b1[[i]])
}
```